# FQL multi query optimisation

Tags: sql, facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I'm trying to get my head around whether it would be possible to do something with an FQL multi-query rather than multiple API calls.

Here is my code:

```
var queries : Object = {

"user_list":"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = "+uid

,"event_id":"SELECT eid, start_time, end_time, location, pic, name FROM event 
WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #user_list) 
AND rsvp_status='attending') AND start_time > " + nowSecs + " 
AND start_time < " + (nowSecs + 2500000) + " ORDER BY start_time ASC LIMIT 20"

"user_name":"SELECT name FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM event_member 
WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM #event_id) 
AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #user_list) AND rsvp_status='attending')"
 };
```

At the moment there are too many results being fetched in my 'event_id' query, I currently get the full list of events for each person stored in the 'user_list' query, which I would ideally like to only get 1 event for each person, and then sort those results. I can't seem to do this, using LIMIT I only get 1 result back in total, but not for each person.

Additionally, and more importantly, I only want one result per event in the 'user_name' query, at the moment I sometimes get multiple members who are attending the same event, and this causes problems as I have no way of matching the user names up with their corresponding event once the results are received. I have also noticed that if the same user is going to 
two different events contained in 'event_id' there is only one instance of their name in the result, which is also undesirable.

At the moment I am making 20 API calls once I have the 'event_id' results and then sorting the data returned, which is really slowing down my app.

Can anyone suggest how I could achieve what I want, and thus optimise the queries please?

Sorry for the long post, but this has been getting on my tits for days!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell in reading through, you want to get:

1. A list of all of your friends,
2. The most recent event that each friend has said they'd attend.

This is very similar to the problem presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823939/selecting-sum-of-top-2-values-within-a-table-with-multiple-group-in-sql/3829713#3829713), with the exception that he's going after 2 results for each item and you're searching for only one.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't really help as the facebook FQL language does not have all of those commands at it's disposal. I solved this somehow but I can't remember how, it was back in February!