# selecting top N rows for each group in a table

Tags: sql, ranking

I am facing a very common issue regarding "Selecting top N rows for each group in a table".

Consider a table with `id, name, hair_colour, score` columns.

I want a resultset such that, for each hair colour, get me top 3 scorer names.

To solve this i got exactly what i need on [Rick Osborne's blogpost "sql-getting-top-n-rows-for-a-grouped-query"](http://rickosborne.org/blog/index.php/2008/01/07/sql-getting-top-n-rows-for-a-grouped-query/)

That solution doesn't work as expected when my scores are equal.

In above example the result as follow.

```
 id  name  hair  score  ranknum
---------------------------------
 12  Kit    Blonde  10  1
  9  Becca  Blonde  9  2
  8  Katie  Blonde  8  3
  3  Sarah  Brunette 10  1    
  4  Deborah Brunette 9  2 - ------- - - > if
  1  Kim  Brunette 8  3
```

Consider the row `4 Deborah Brunette 9 2`. If this also has same score (10) same as Sarah, then ranknum will be 2,2,3 for "Brunette" type of hair.

What's the solution to this?

Comment: There's a solution for this over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823939/ in case you're not using the newer SQL Servers.

Answer (score 17):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or newer, you can use the ranking functions and a CTE to achieve this:

```
;WITH HairColors AS
(SELECT id, name, hair, score, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hair ORDER BY score DESC) as 'RowNum'
)
SELECT id, name, hair, score
FROM HairColors
WHERE RowNum <= 3
```

This CTE will "partition" your data by the value of the `hair` column, and each partition is then order by score (descending) and gets a row number; the highest score for each partition is 1, then 2 etc.

So if you want to the TOP 3 of each group, select only those rows from the CTE that have a `RowNum` of 3 or less (1, 2, 3) --> there you go!

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hair ORDER BY score DESC) as 'RowNum') the bracket in this line is not balanced. is this compatible with db2 sql grammar?

Comment: @zinking: thanks - there was one closing parens too many.. fixed it! I don't know off-hand if DB2 supports this (don't know DB2 enough) - but it's definitely an ANSI/ISO SQL standard construct - not a Microsoft invented feature :-)

Comment: Shit, this just made my day! What an introduction to CTEs!

Answer (score 0):

The way the algorithm comes up with the rank, is to count the number of rows in the cross-product with a score equal to or greater than the girl in question, in order to generate rank.  Hence in the problem case you're talking about, Sarah's grid would look like

```
a.name | a.score | b.name  | b.score
-------+---------+---------+--------
Sarah  | 9       | Sarah   | 9
Sarah  | 9       | Deborah | 9
```

and similarly for Deborah, which is why both girls get a rank of 2 here.

The problem is that when there's a tie, all girls take the *lowest* value in the tied range due to this count, when you'd want them to take the highest value instead.  I think a simple change can fix this:

Instead of a greater-than-or-equal comparison, use a strict greater-than comparison to count the number of girls who are strictly better.  Then, add one to that and you have your rank (which will deal with ties as appropriate).  So the inner select would be:

```
SELECT a.id, COUNT(*) + 1 AS ranknum
FROM girl AS a
  INNER JOIN girl AS b ON (a.hair = b.hair) AND (a.score < b.score)
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
```

Can anyone see any problems with this approach that have escaped my notice?

Comment: Doesn't that run in quadratic time ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this compound select which handles OP problem properly

```
SELECT g.* FROM girls as g
WHERE g.score > IFNULL( (SELECT g2.score FROM girls as g2
                WHERE g.hair=g2.hair ORDER BY g2.score DESC LIMIT 3,1), 0)
```

Note that you need to use IFNULL here to handle case when table *girls* has less rows for some type of *hair* then we want to see in sql answer (in OP case it is 3 items).