# MySQL finding the most expensive in each zip code

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a table called Products with the schema (name, city, state, zip_code price).

And I want to find the most expensive products' name for a given state's each zip_code.

I wrote

```
SELECT zip_code, MAX(price)
FROM products
WHERE products.state = 'NJ'
GROUP BY zip_code
```

as a subquery, but I couldn't figure out displaying product name and price per zip_code in 'NJ'

I would appreciate if you can help me,
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [selecting top N rows for each group in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998529/selecting-top-n-rows-for-each-group-in-a-table)

Comment: `SELECT name, zip_code, MAX(price)` ... didn't work?

Comment: @TheJumpingFrog: That doesn't return the records relevant to `MAX(price)`, it just returns an arbitrary record from each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
      t.name, t.city, t.zip_code, t.price
FROM  
       ( SELECT zip_code
              , MAX(price) as price 
         FROM products 
         WHERE state = 'NJ' 
         GROUP BY zip_code
       ) AS tm 
    JOIN
        products as t
            ON  tm.zip_code = t.zip_code 
            AND tm.price = t.price
WHERE 
        t.state = 'NJ'
```

Comment: @safarov: Why did you delete your answer?

Answer (score 3):

This should work, though I can't vouch for it's efficiency.  Per comment, here's an update that pulls back all records with price equal to the max price per zip code.

```
SELECT *
  FROM products p1
 WHERE p1.state = 'NJ'
   AND p1.price = (select max(price) from products p2
                   where p1.zip_code = p2.zip_code)
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98f6d/2

Comment: yes, i think it will work but the only problem is, i want to find all products which's price is maximum, not just the top one

Comment: Righto, updated to match by price instead of just the first record.  Though I'm thinking @safarov's solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT name,price,zip_code
FROM products
WHERE state='NJ' AND price=(SELECT MAX(price) FROM products)
```

Comment: I think that won't help either. It'll just forward the name of max priced entity

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will (either way) need a composite index on *products.state,products.zip_code*.

Try the following:

```
SELECT p.zip_code, MAX(p.price) AS max_price, 
(
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(products.id AS CHAR)) FROM products 
  WHERE products.state = 'NJ' AND 
  products.zip_code = p.zip_code AND products.price = MAX(p.price) 
) AS product_ids
FROM products p WHERE p.state = 'NJ' GROUP BY p.zip_code ORDER BY NULL
```

**Note:**
GROUP_CONCAT has a limitation regarding the maximum length of the resulting string, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len . If you are missing some IDs, this could be the reason.