# How can I select all entries with the highest version?

Tags: sql

I have  a table called `documents` that has the fields id, title, version and content.

Now I want to get all ids (or rows) for every title with the highest version.

Suppose I have the following data:

```
+----+-------+---------+---------+
| id | title | version | content |
+----+-------+---------+---------+
|  2 | foo   |       1 | abc1    |
|  3 | foo   |       2 | abc2    |
|  4 | foo   |       3 | abc3    |
|  5 | bar   |       1 | abcd1   |
|  6 | bar   |       2 | abcd2   |
|  7 | baz   |       1 | abcde1  |
+----+-------+---------+---------+
```

I want to receive either the ids 4,6,7 or the whole rows for these entries.

Performance is not an issue as there will be only a few hundred entries.

Comment: You can group them. A great example is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998529/selecting-top-n-rows-for-each-group-in-a-table

Answer (score 4):

To retrieve the entire rows, you need to `GROUP BY version` with a `MAX()` aggregate, and join that as a subquery against the whole table to pull in the remaining columns.  The `JOIN` condition will need to be against the combination of `title, version` since together they uniquely identify a title's greatest version.

The following should work independently of the RDBMS you are using:

```
SELECT 
  documents.id,
  documents.title, 
  documents.version,
  documents.content
FROM 
  documents
  JOIN (
    /* subquery pulls greatest version per title */
    SELECT
      title,
      MAX(version) AS version
    FROM documents
    GROUP BY title
    /* title, version pair is joined back against the main table */
  ) maxversions ON (documents.title = maxversions.title AND documents.version = maxversions.version)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple group by:

```
select max(version)
from documents
group by title
```

You can join back to documents, if you like, to get the full document information.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM dataz
WHERE version IN (
  SELECT TOP 1 version
  FROM dataz
  ORDER BY version DESC
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get the IDs you want:

```
  Select max(id) as id from documents
group by title
  having count(1) = max(version)
order by id
```