# How can I query T-SQL to get "Top 10 'x' for each of 'y'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

OK, I've found some close references to what I'm trying to do, but the examples given and the answers were either too simple for me to extrapolate from, or too complex for me to grasp. I'm not a professional DBA, just a poor network tech who has to write a report in Visual Studio 2012 for the Sales dept., so please be kind.

Basically, I need to write a query in the report designer that pulls from 2 tables - 'custextract' and 'histextract'. The result is 30 fields long (ALL of them needed in the report so I learned fast not to try and group in the query).

The final report has to create a "Customer Contact Page" for sales people to take to the field - one page per customer. The top portion is basic customer information and comes entirely from the customer table, and the lower portion is a table of sales history information (period-to-date, year-to-date, last-year, etc.) by product line. There are about 30 possible product lines but most customers only buy from a few. The report should only return the TOP(10) rows for EACH Customer ORDERED BY year-to-date DESC - if that makes sense. The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT custextract.*, histextract.*
FROM custextract 
INNER JOIN histextract 
        ON custextract.[cusx-cust-no] = histextract.[hisx-cust]
WHERE (custextract.[cusx-ecall-select] = 'Y')
ORDER BY histextract.[hisx-sales-ytd] DESC
```

The obvious problem is that if I include TOP(10) in the SELECT, I get only the top 10 total, not per customer. I'm assuming I need to select a Count(histextract.[hisx-cust]) AS number and then do some kind of iterative loop based on number, joining all the results - but I'm totally lost how to effectively accomplish this. Select, From, Where, Order by, Into is basically the limits of my querying skill.

I am populating those two tables from extracts of an ISAM database coming over as .csv files using a stored procedure (I still haven't figured out how to trigger it, but that's later). Basically just a TRUNCATE and BULK INSERT operation. But, if it would make sense to create a third table to hold sorted and filtered data and use that update procedure to continue on and create the desired dataset (then just use that third table in Report Designer) I'm open to it - just don't know how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you're trying to do is a common problem called **top N per group**.  Here's one such solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998529/selecting-top-n-rows-for-each-group-in-a-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with a join but I think you can get the idea

```
WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
    SELECT SalesOrderID, Customer,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Customer BY SalesOrderID) AS RowNumber
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
) 
SELECT SalesOrderID, Customer  
FROM OrderedOrders 
WHERE RowNumber <= 10;
```

[ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

OP needed more than the idea

```
WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
    SELECT custextract.[cusx-cust-no], histextract.[hisx-sales-ytd], 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (custextract.[cusx-cust-no] BY histextract.[hisx-sales-ytd] desc) AS RowNumber
    FROM custextract 
    INNER JOIN histextract 
        ON custextract.[cusx-cust-no] = histextract.[hisx-cust]
    WHERE (custextract.[cusx-ecall-select] = 'Y')
) 
SELECT OrderedOrders.[cusx-cust-no], OrderedOrders.[hisx-sales-ytd] 
FROM OrderedOrders 
WHERE RowNumber <= 10;
```

Comment: It has to have a CTE because you cannot put WHERE RowNumber in the same query that generates it (Ver 2012 may be different)

Comment: What's a CTE?  That's why I get confused - I have a hard time translating using one table and 2 fields to selecting all the fields from 2 tables and joining them together. Is this what I should be attempting...  WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Customer BY SalesOrderID) AS RowNumber
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
) 
SELECT OrderedOrders.*, SecondTable.*  
FROM OrderedOrders
INNER JOIN SecondTable 
        ON OrderedOrders.Field1 = SecondTable.Field1
WHERE RowNumber <= 10 AND SecondTable.Field2='X';

Comment: OK HOW do you guys get the formatted code in there - that comment just butchered what I actually tried to insert.

Comment: The WITH (  ) is a CTE.  Go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/ and search on TSQL CTE

Comment: You can also wrap it in the query to do the RowNumber. It's not as cool as an CTE - but for some, more readable. I tend to use CTE's for recursive purposes only. `SELECT OrderedOrders.[cusx-cust-no], OrderedOrders.[hisx-sales-ytd] FROM ( SELECT custextract.[cusx-cust-no], histextract.[hisx-sales-ytd], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (custextract.[cusx-cust-no] BY histextract.[hisx-sales-ytd] desc) AS RowNumber FROM custextract INNER JOIN histextract ON custextract.[cusx-cust-no] = histextract.[hisx-cust] WHERE (custextract.[cusx-ecall-select]='Y') ) OrderedOrders WHERE RowNumber <= 10;`

Comment: You'll find on StackOverflow, if you mention the word CTE - even if your solution doesn't include a CTE - you'll be upvoted until you die.

Comment: Oops! I still can't select ALL the fields from both tables. I thought this would work... but not so much...   `SELECT OrderedYTD.* 
FROM ( 
 SELECT custextract.*, histextract.*, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (custextract.custno BY histextract.salesytd desc) AS RowNumber 
 FROM custextract 
 INNER JOIN histextract 
  ON custextract.custno = histextract.custno 
 WHERE (custextract.ecall='Y') ) OrderedYTD 
WHERE RowNumber <= 10`  generates errors from the very first *

Comment: Never mind - apparently in 2012 you have to spell out PARTITION BY and ORDER BY for it to work. Works like a charm now. Thanks again to all.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't intend to truly make an answer in the comments.  I was just suggesting w/o testing.